# Cannot view new data created via Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am facing an issue in which, I cannot view some data from Hive. Steps to reproduce the issue. Create a table

```
drop table if exists hive_parquet_nulls_test ;

create table hive_parquet_nulls_test (
name String
)
 partitioned by (report_date DATE)
 stored as PARQUET;
```

Then create a data frame and with a new column and load them

```
import java.sql.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._



case class Person(name : String, age : Int, report_date : Date)

val df = sc.parallelize(
    Seq(Person("Steve", 30, Date.valueOf("2016-09-30")), 
        Person("James", 29, Date.valueOf("2016-09-30")))).toDF

df.show(false)

spark.sql(s"ALTER TABLE hive_parquet_nulls_test  ADD COLUMNS (age integer)");
spark.sql(s"REFRESH TABLE hive_parquet_nulls_test");

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("hive_parquet_nulls_test")
```

At this time, we can see all data from hive. Then we will create another dataframe with a new column

```
val df = spark.table("hive_parquet_nulls_test")

val newDF = df.withColumn("address", lit("123 Green Avenue, London"))

newDF.show(false)


spark.sql(s"ALTER TABLE hive_parquet_nulls_test  ADD COLUMNS (address string)")
spark.sql(s"REFRESH TABLE hive_parquet_nulls_test")

spark.sql(s"describe hive_parquet_nulls_test")

val finalFieldNames = newDF.schema.fieldNames

val finalPartitionedDF = newDF.select($"name", $"age", $"address", $"report_date")
      .cache()

finalPartitionedDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("hive_parquet_nulls_test_test")


spark.table("hive_parquet_nulls_test").show(false)
```

Once loaded, only address column is showing as null. And that happens only in hive. Spark displays the columns perfectly (So data in there, hive is struggling to read this column). Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Show create table in hive is showing up the new column added ? and can you check the updatetimestamp of the ddl in hive, also can you try msck repair table. Lastly verify if the spark is referring to the same hive/hive-site.xml as the hive shell that you were using

Comment: You have added address column in hive_parquet_nulls_test table but writing dataframe to hive_parquet_nulls_test_test

Comment: @KSNidhin, yes show create is showing the new column added and the timestamp is updated too. I even added a load_timestamp column and checked that the timestamp is after the table is updated. (Data is there and presto and spark and display the data, but Hive is not able to read it) Also tried msck repair table. Regarding the point of if spark is using the same hive-site.xml, no. I am using an emr (spark and hive have their own hive-site.xml). Can you point me to any documentation where I can override the spark settings to use hive's hive-site.xml. Thanks

Comment: @RamdevSharma - apologies that was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to see data in first attempt for age column since partition was not created yet in hive so hive used schema that is currently available which includes age column.

On second attempt, you were writing to existing partition of hive, so hive is applying null values for all columns that were added after partition created.

If you write new data into any new partition then you will see data immediately.

If you drop partition and then write same data frame that you have cached then hive will also show address when querying.

```
spark.sql("alter table hive_parquet_nulls_test drop partition(report_date='2016-09-30')");
finalPartitionedDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("hive_parquet_nulls_test")
```

On hive shell:

```
select address from hive_parquet_nulls_test;
OK
123 Green Avenue, London
123 Green Avenue, London
```

It seems it is happening due to hive bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6131